# Issue with computed observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout-2.2.0.js. I have the following model:

```
function Person(name, age, city)
{
 this.Name = ko.observable(name);
 this.Age = ko.observable(age);
 this.City = ko.observable(city);

 ko.computed(function(){

   //Is there any way to execute this section whenever Name, Age, City any 
   //of this observable changes without including this.Name, this.Age and 
   //this.City inside it

 }, this).extend({ throttle: 500 });
}
```

I know what i am asking is little bit strange but i want to know is there any way to do this?

Comment: Short answer: No. What are you trying to achieve, maybe there are different ways to solve it instead of hacking the cumputed?

Comment: I would think you just need to subscribe to the model.

Comment: yaa subscribe is the good point, but i want to use throttle extenders, can we use this in subscribe ? because i do not want to get the live changes of my observable

Comment: That's a good question, I don't have the answer to it.

Comment: Why don't you want to include those observables inside the computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to call `ko.toJS(this)` in your computed.  This is generally used to build a "clean" object out of a view model. As part of building that object it will unwrap all of the observables (which creates dependencies).  So, then your computed will be triggered whenever any of the dependencies change.

This is the basis of things like a "dirty flag": http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

You can use `throttle` with your computed in this manner.

Answer (score 3):

use a custom binding. custom binding has an 'update' function inside it. And that update function get called automatically when any observable value get changed

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html